# Is it encouraged, or even beneficial to use Flash/HTML Canvas optimization when drawing shapes

Tags: html, flash, optimization, canvas

I am starting to get a grasp of the HTML canvas and I wanted to know if it is encouraged to use optimization techniques. In games for example, is it encouraged to use bounding boxes and only redraw the portion of the screen that needs redrawing, or do people just blindly redraw everything. I ask this b/c I am creating a new engine for canvas and imposing bounding boxes complicates things greatly (ie. the user no longer has the freedom to quickly draw things to the stage).

Comment: Optimization is an anti-pattern. Of course, I'm kidding. `:P`

Comment: Always worth mentioning, as well... http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @JaredFarrish, good too know before some zealous moderator, inevitably, closes this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it's almost always better to draw only what has changed on the screen at any one time. Attempting to draw everything causes unnecessary rasterisation of the images being drawn into one output image, when it's not even going to change on the screen.

In a small game I made a year ago, I was drawing a 2D array of tiles on the screen and getting around 15 frames per second. When I changed it to draw only the tiles visible on the screen, it was an amazing improvement. It will improve in this circumstance too.

Comment: I noticed that too. Without optimization, even a few circles with gradients had a noticeable delay on mouse over events. With bounding boxes, I can draw hundreds (provided I cache the gradients as images). I am just worried that people are going to go "I can't draw a simple line from A to B? Forget it"